# Fluid Image within a fixed Div not re-sizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Thanks in advance for any and all help and responses. I have a fixed div which floats at the bottom of the screen and is used as ad space for a mobile version of a website. The live version can be found here: http://www.catholiccourier.com/?mobileFormat=true . For some reason, when I try to re-size the browser window, the image inside the fixed div does not seem to shrink properly. If I resize the window abruptly the image shrinks, but it wont resize the same way as the header logo for example. Also it does not seem to stay centered. I have tried margin:0 auto; and text-align:center on the outer div, but it does not seem to work. There are some script tags inside the div as well as noscript, and I am wondering if they may be the cause of the issue.

You can see all of the code in the live website, but here is a copy of some of the code.

```
<div id="adSpace" align="center">
    <script language="javascript" src="http://www.catholiccourier.com/banman/a.aspx?ZoneID=43&amp;Task=Get&amp;IFR=False&amp;Browser=NETSCAPE4&amp;PageID=9311&amp;SiteID=2&amp;Random=1375796513537"></script>
    <a href="http://catholiccourier.com/banman/a.aspx?Task=Click&amp;ZoneID=43&amp;CampaignID=265&amp;AdvertiserID=79&amp;BannerID=242&amp;SiteID=2&amp;RandomNumber=655331242&amp;Keywords=" target="_Blank" class="ui-link">
        <img src="http://catholiccourier.com/banman/ads/3/HOLY-SEP-REWORK_fix.gif" width="728" height="90" alt="Holy Sepulchre Cemetery 585-458-4110" align="Center" border="0">
    </a>
    <br>
    <noscript>
        &lt;a href="http://www.catholiccourier.com/banman/a.aspx?ZoneID=43&amp;amp;Task=Click&amp;amp;Mode=HTML&amp;amp;SiteID=2&amp;amp;PageID=9311" target="_blank"&gt; &lt;img src="http://www.catholiccourier.com/banman/a.aspx?ZoneID=43&amp;amp;Task=Get&amp;amp;Mode=HTML&amp;amp;SiteID=2&amp;amp;PageID=9311" width="728" height="90" border="0" alt=""&gt;&lt;/a&gt; 
    </noscript>
</div>
```

Please help and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use position:absolute for your div

```
.ui-mobile #adSpace {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #e6e6e6;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
max-height: 90px;
z-index: 9999;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I do not understand why it works in absolute but not in fixed. However, unfortunately we do want to have the div (adspace) float on the bottom of the screen, while users scroll, so I would need to have it set to fixed. Any other ideas? I tried to wrap the content within another div, but that did not work for me. I suppose I can go more complex with it and set it to absolute and then javascript it to the bottom while user scrolls. I do not know if this is the most efficient solution.

Comment: I got it to work. I wrapped the content in another div and I set that div to relative:
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
min-width: 100%;
max-width: 405px;